# ¿Cómo puedo activar/desactivar botones con el mismo id y clase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Los botones los genero mediante ajax

```
 $(data).each(function(i, v) {
   $("#containerfpagos").append('<button type="submit"  data-id="' + v.id_fpago + '"style="margin:1rem" class="btn btn-primary shadow-button" name="fpago" id="fpago"><div class="info"><h3>' + v.descrip_fpago + '</h3></div></button>');
  })
```

Tengo esta función: aquí es donde quiero que, si yo doy un clic al botón, este tome la propiedad `disabled`, y cuando dé clic a otro botón, este tome la propiedad `disabled` y que al otro que está `disabled` se le quite la propiedad (los botones los genero dinámicamente, la única diferencia entre ellos es el `data-id`).

```
$('body').on('click', '#fpago', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        if (this.disabled) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que no pueden existir dos elementos con un mismo ID, eso deberás corregirlo. Para el problema, lo que te recomiendo hacer es usar una misma clase CSS para todos los botones (una auxiliar para el caso), poner un evento onlclick para esa clase y deshabilitar todos los botones. Y por último habilitas el que fue clickeado (this). Algo así:

```
$(".btn-aux").prop('disabled', true);
$(this).prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Trekkium, los identificadores deben ser únicos en la pagina (para referencia mira [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)), por ende usar clases es la manera más adecuada.

Si quieres hacerlo con Javascript plano puedes hacerlo así:

```
const htmlElements = document.querySelectorAll('.clase'); 
/* o para id puedes usar:
const htmlElements = document.querySelectorAll('#identificador'); 
*/
htmlElements.forEach(elemento => elemento.disabled = true);
```

Tenga en cuenta que `htmlElements` es una variable de tipo `NodeList`, es decir, si quiere usar funciones de Arrays como `map` o `reduce` debe primero transformarla en arreglo, así:

```
const items = Array.from(htmlElements);
items.map(/* ... */);
items.reduce(/* ... */);
```